# Bind CollectionViewSource in Xaml Page for Individual Fields like TextBox

Tags: wpf

In XAML DataContext, I have Collection View Source that holds Collection of object regarding Customer.( I'm doing MVVM pattern for this.) If I was Navigate Next,Prev,Last,First via. We need to Bind Current Customer from the Source without proxy Model(Local Object called Customer). How can i bind the item?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the data context of textbox?

Comment: In CustomerCollection we have list of Customers. I need to bind Current Customer CustNumber from CollectionViewSource.

Comment: Where do you bind the CVS? If its an ItemsControl then set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=True and then Bind your Control to the SelectedItem of the ItemsControl using the ElementName syntax.